# saveAsTextFile() to write the final RDD as single text file - Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am working on a batch application using Apache Spark, i wanted to write the final RDD as text file, currently i am using `saveAsTextFile("filePath")` method available in RDD.

My text file contains the fields delimited with `\u0001` delimiter. So in the model class toString() method i added all the fields seperated with `\u0001` delimiter.

is this the correct way to handle this? or any other best approach available?

Also what if i iterate the RDD and write the file content using `FileWriter` class available in Java?

Please advise on this.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write as a single file there are a few options. If your writing to HDFS or a similar distributed store you can first `coalesce` your RDD down to a single partition (note your data must then fit on a single worker), or you could `collect` the data to the driver and then use a filewriter.

Comment: Thanks. Is saveAsTextFile() option internally uses Java FileWriter() or something else.

Comment: Instead of collecting you should use coalesce as bringing data back to driver is not recommended

Comment: coalesce has the same effect of bringing all the data on to a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean copyMerge(SparkConf sparkConf, JavaRDD rdd, String dstPath) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Configuration hadoopConf = sparkConf.hadoopConfiguration();
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", awsAccessKey);
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", awsSecretKey);
    String tempFolder = "s3://bucket/folder";
    rdd.saveAsTextFile(tempFolder);
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(tempFolder), hadoopConfig);
    return FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(tempFolder), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, hadoopConfig, null);
}
```

This solution is for S3 or any HDFS system. Achieved in two steps:

1. Save the RDD by saveAsTextFile, this generates multiple files in the folder.
2. Run Hadoop "copyMerge".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing collect and collecting it to driver I would rather suggest to use coalesce which would be good in reducing memory problems