# How to store the text file on the Master?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Standalone clusters to run the ALS algorithm. The predictions are being stored to the textfile using:

```
saveAsTextFile(path)
```

But the text file is being stored on the clusters. I want to store the text file on the Master.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [saveAsTextFile() to write the final RDD as single text file - Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145737/saveastextfile-to-write-the-final-rdd-as-single-text-file-apache-spark)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Writing to a single file is not the issue. I want to save the   output file on the Master instead of the slaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior. `path` is resolved on the machine it
is executed, the slaves. I'd recommend to either use a cluster FS
(e.g. HDFS) or `.collect()` your data so you can save them locally on
the master. Beware of OOM if your data is large.

Comment: I used it as `val data=predictions.collect()`, and now I cannot use `saveAsTextFile()` because I get this error: _saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[String]_ . I need to convert `data` to **RDD**, so I tried `val rdd=sc.parallelize(data)` and `rdd.saveAsTextFile(path)`. But still the text file is being stored on the slaves machines.

Comment: Yeah, sure. `saveAsTextFile` only works on slaves. You'll have to do your own writing with java stuff, it's local now.

Comment: I did not get it. I need more information on "own writing with java stuff". I am new to apache spark.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java

Comment: Yes, thanks. To store RDD using printwriter I used `for (line <- rdd.toLocalIterator) {writer.println(line)}` from [here](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2015/12/15/Spark-Writing-Driver-FIleSystem/). Thanks a lot for the help.